# Why 'irb' shell exits instantaneously in docker command

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, irb

This is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM ruby:2.4.0-alpine
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY Gemfile ./Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock ./Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install -j 20
COPY . .
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: "irb"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

I expected that `docker-compose up` will open an irb shell, however the shell exits right away. Why does it exit?

What can I do to use irb shell through docker?

Comment: I am adding some links here for future ref: 

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21147/what-are-pseudo-terminals-pty-tty

https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`docker-compose up` does not allocate a TTY for IRB, so IRB exits immediately. You can achieve what you want with either `docker-compose run` or `docker-compose exec` which both allocate a pseudo-TTY:

```sh
$ docker-compose run web irb
Creating compose-irb_web_run ... done
irb(main):001:0>
```

Alternatively, if you modify the command in your `docker-compose.yml` (see below), run `docker-compose up` you can execute `irb` inside of the running container with `docker-compose exec web irb`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: sh -c 'while true; do sleep 30; done'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

Comment: Thanks @ezekiel , Could you also comment on why does the irb command (the way i used it) exits instantaneously ?

Comment: @AsadIqbal Because `docker-compose up` does not allocate a TTY and irb needs one.

Comment: This is a great answer and it helped. I've also looked what a tty is and in case anyone is wondering, in short it makes the terminal interactive and allows for user input which makes sense why irb needs one. The fact `docker compose` does not allocate a tty ends up closing the container so the solution above works great to keep the container running.